# How can I find if a particular package exists on my Android device?

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

How can I find whether a particular package or application, say: `com.android.abc`, exists on my Android device?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Call any of the below method with the package name.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

// ...

    public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
        PackageManager pm;

        pm = getPackageManager();        
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

```
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

 public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
   PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
   try {
     PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
   } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
     return false;
   }  
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Rasel, I was looking for this only. Thank U very much.

Comment: What do I have to import to get this to work? I get `cannot resolve symbol 'PackageManager'` error.

Comment: the second method is faster

Comment: Does this require any permission? i am still getting false!

Comment: @EmonHossainMunna depending on the Android version, you now need to declare the packages you interact with in the manifest: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element

Answer (score 14):

Without using a try-catch block or iterating through a bunch of packages:

```
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (intent == null) {
        return false;
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Kotlin**

```
fun isPackageExist(context: Context, target: String): Boolean {
     return context.packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0).find { info -> info.packageName == target } != null
}
```

**Edit: Extension Function**

```
fun Context.isPackageExist(target: String): Boolean {
     return packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0).find { info -> info.packageName == target } != null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

We can check like this:

```
 if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.software.webview") == true && isPackageExisted("com.google.android.webview")) {
            if (Constant.isNetworkConnected(Activity.this)) {
                 //Your Intent 
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resources.getString(R.string.internet_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }   else
            {
                Constant.showDialog(Activity.this,"Please install the webview");
            }
    }
```

Make method for package check ! this credit goes to "Kavi" https://stackoverflow.com/a/30708227/6209105

```
public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage) {
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;

    pm = getPackageManager();
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage))
        {
            return true;
        }
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You should use `PackageManager`'s function called [`getInstalledPackages()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29) to get the list of all installed packages and the search for the one you are interested in. Note that package name is located in [`PackageInfo.packageName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#packageName) field.

Answer (score 2):

Since some devices have reported that the "getInstalledPackages" can cause TransactionTooLargeException (check [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=95749), [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93717) and [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69276)), I think you should also have a fallback like I did below.

This issue was supposed to be fixed on Android 5.1 (read [**here**](https://paste.teknik.io/1010)), but some still reported about it.

```
public static List<String> getInstalledPackages(final Context context) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        List<PackageInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (PackageInfo packageInfo : apps)
            result.add(packageInfo.packageName);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        //we don't care why it didn't succeed. We'll do it using an alternative way instead
    }
    // use fallback:
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm list packages");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            final String packageName = line.substring(line.indexOf(':') + 1);
            result.add(packageName);
        }
        closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void closeQuietly(final Closeable closeable) {
    if (closeable == null)
        return;
    try {
        closeable.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use adb:

```
adb shell "pm list packages"|cut -f 2 -d ":"
```

it will list all installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pm.getPackageUid() instead of iterating over the pm.getInstalledApplications()

```
 boolean isPackageInstalled;
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();   
 int flags = 0; 
        try 
        {   
              pm.getPackageUid(packageName,flags);               
              isPackageInstalled = true;    
        }   
        catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException nnfe) 
        {   
            isPackageInstalled = false; 
        }                   
 return isPackageInstalled;
```

Comment: getPackageUid - Added in API level 24, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Package visibility filtering changes](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) in Android 11, you need to add this permission to your manifest to be able to list installed apps:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>`

but Google doesn't recommend to use this way. You should use `<queries>` tag instead:

```
<manifest ...>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.app.package" />
        ...
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

And in your code:

```
fun isAppInstalled(context: Context, packageId: String): Boolean {
    return try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            context.packageManager
                .getApplicationInfo(packageId, PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(0))
        } else {
            context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageId, 0)
        }
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
}
```