# Check and Install other application from other android

Tags: android

I want to create small application which when I start this small application in main activity I want to check if other application for example "barcode" is installed on my phone.

- If yes I want to start application "barcode"
- If no I want to install this application from google play.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with following code if the application is installed

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean app_installed = false;
try
{
     pm.getPackageInfo("com.package.Barcode", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
     app_installed = true;
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
     app_installed = false;
}
return app_installed ;
```

And following code redirects the user to the play store for downloading the application

```
String appName = "com.package.Barcode";    
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

How to open an existing app you can find here:

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

And how to check if app exists you can find here:

[How can I learn whether a particular package exists on my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-to-know-perticular-package-application-exist-in-the-device)