# How to install two apk at once?

Tags: android, apk

I have a requirement for my app. I have an app for displaying books and an app for reading book basically a `Viewer`. I have two questions :

1. Is it possible to install both apk at once at the starting ?
2. Is it possible to integrate two apk ?

And when i click on the first option that is the app i am getting this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{jp.co.atori.A12022411/jp.co.atori.A12022411A.FSDMainLauncherActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jp.co.atori.A12022411A.FSDMainLauncherActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/jp.co.atori.A12022411-1.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jp.co.atori.A12022411A.FSDMainLauncherActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/jp.co.atori.A12022411-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

After changing manifest it looks like:

```
<activity
    android:name="jp.co.atori.A12022411.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="aircel-bookshelfviewer" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="jp.co.atori.A12022411A.FSDMainLauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:taskAffinity="com.jp.co.atori.A12022411A.FSDMainLauncherActivity.viewer"
    android:permission="com.smartebook.android.fsdreader.permission"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="FSDREADERAPPLICATION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: make your activity's category as Launcher:
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: I am sorry if the comment may have offended anyone. My solution was already in the answer, and already upvoted. But as for the question it was really not researched and I may as well say not given enough though. SO is not for every trivial question. I mean look OP has code to both app then why not simply merge them. Is that really a problem or lack of effort.

Comment: Yes may be lack of effort and also lack of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply package everything as one application (APK), and provide 2 separate launchers, one for the Reader, one for the Viewer.  Your manifest would look something like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewerActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/viewer_logo"
        android:label="@string/viewer_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ReaderActivity"
        android:taskAffinity="com.yourapp.reader"
        android:icon="@drawable/reader_logo"
        android:label="@string/reader_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So after users have installed your app, they will see 2 application icons: one that takes you to your Reader, one that takes you to your Viewer.  These are 2 entry points to the same app (but it appears to the user that they are 2 different apps).

Comment: when i am trying to launch the viewer than an alert is coming "Complete Action Using" 1) App & 2) Viewer. When i click viewer than it is working ok but when i click the app, the app crashes as it can't be used to read books. Can you help me in removing that. I have no idea why it is coming.

Comment: Hmmm.  I am surprised to hear that alert.  I have a similar app with 2 launchers and I get no such alert.  The only difference I can see is that I have defined one of my activities with the following attribute: android:launchMode="singleTop".  I doubt this will fix it however.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your manifest?   As for the crash, I suggest you examine the LogCat output or debug the application for more details.

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection, I see one more important detail.  One of my launchers has a "android:taskAffinity" attribute that names a separate task for that activity.  I have edited my answer above to include this.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: I have posted my manifest and the exception also. Please can you check and let me know if there is any error.

Comment: If you can check whether the android:taskAffinity is correct in my manifest or not

Comment: taskAffinity looks OK, but I suggest you read the docs at android.developer.com to be sure.  My next suggestion is to start whittling-down your activities until they more closely resemble the ones I posted.  Here are 2 suggestions to get you started: (1) Remove the intent filter with action VIEW.  (2) Add icon attributes for each activity, and make sure that they are different.

Answer (score 0):

When user installs one app, on its first startup you can simply check if the other one is installed on the device. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-to-know-perticular-package-application-exist-in-the-device). If not installed, you can fire an intent for the play store and user installs the other app. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android).