# Check if the Google Maps application is installed on the device

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to access the Google Maps appication from an IBM Worklight application by the following command line:

```
geo:37.786971,-122.399677
```

Is there any way to find out if the Google Maps application (or any map client application) exist on the mobile device?

Comment: refer to :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-to-know-perticular-package-application-exist-in-the-device

Comment: If my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can write a [Cordova plug-in in Worklight](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf) that will [check whether Google Maps (or any other application) is installed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-to-know-perticular-package-application-exist-in-the-device).

** The Worklight Getting Started website is down, [but for now you can get the same information in the IBM Worklight Information Center.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.doc/wl_home.html)