# Check if a package is installed in Android

Tags: android, package

I would like to check if a package is installed in my app.
How I can do that ?
I need to add some permission for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please search the site before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-can-i-learn-whether-a-particular-package-exists-on-my-android-device

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo("PackageName",PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
```

And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)