# Tango app for all android devices

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, tango

I am exploring tango sdk and find some things that i am not able to understand
there is an app called

istaging :- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iStaging.furniture

and there is another app

istaging for tango:- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.istaging.furniture.tango

The simple app works for all normal android devices and app which says for tango shows "app is not compatible with your device

now my question is 
is there any possibility that can develop app with tango sdk and works for normal android devices?
if yes please guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Tango SDK only works on Tango-enabled devices, which at the time of writing, are the Yellowstone Devkit and the Phab Pro 2.

If you want to create an app that works on both Android and Tango, first use PackageManager to check if `com.google.tango` is installed on the device, so you can flag whether the phone is Tango-enabled or not. [Learn how to do that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-can-i-learn-whether-a-particular-package-exists-on-my-android-device)

Then build an AR experience using any [AR SDK](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=AR%20SDK%20for%20Android) or [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) as to service the general Android market, and then a seperate, specific Tango experience for the ever-growing Tango phone market.

Hope you found my answer useful.