# How to check if a particular application's package exists or not in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to find whether a particular app exists or not in Android. I have already figured out the package manager and package part but can not figure our how to check this, can anyone help  me out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-can-i-learn-whether-a-particular-package-exists-on-my-android-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I learn whether a particular package exists on my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-can-i-learn-whether-a-particular-package-exists-on-my-android-device)